# Algorithm to determine a tree or not, from the set of edges given

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am trying to solve the problem ["is it a tree"](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PT07Y/) on SPOJ.

> You are given an unweighted, undirected graph. Write a program to check if it's a tree topology.
>   The graph may have up to 10,000 nodes and up to 20,000 edges.

I know the properties of a tree but I couldn't figure out the right data structure/algorithm to detect cycles. Can anyone please give a hint on optimal approach.

I just need a direction, not the code.

Please suggest a basic data structure, not some in-built structure provided in language libraries.

Thanks

Comment: This would probably be better suited for CompSci.

Comment: I guess such questions are supported here under the tag `algorithm`

Comment: They are, but only when they're concrete code problems that show existing implementation. Note that I didn't downvote, as your question is valid in its own right, it just probably doesn't fit too well here.

Comment: Detecting cycles can be done with a simple recursive DFS and an array of nodes that you have visited. The core of this problem is in its size: a DFS on 10,000 nodes will overflow your stack, and a linear search of 20,000 visited nodes will cause timeouts. The trick is to implement DFS without recursion, and to use an efficient membership check as you walk your graph.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight DFS on 10,000 vertices is unlikely to overflow the stack(I don't know the exact stack limit on SPOJ, but the default stack size on most of the platforms should be enough).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to detect a cycle is to use depth first search. It has `O(V + E)` time complexity so it is optimal because you need at least `O(V + E)` time to read the graph.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 ways, but all based on 1 fundamental idea: **A tree with `N` nodes must have `N - 1` edges with no cycles.**

Therefore, the first thing you need to check is if the given `E` and `V` satisfy `E = V - 1`. If they don't just return false, else you could start checking if cycles exist.

As I mentioned, there are at least 2 ways: do a simple **Depth First Search (DFS)** or using a **Union Find Set**.

**DFS Approach:**
The idea is simple: while we are doing DFS and encountered a back edge, a cycle is found. Check [this article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/) for more details on Cycle Detection on graph.

Time complexity of this approach is the complexity of `DFS`, which is `O(V + E)`.

**Union Find Data Structure Approach:**
First you need to know what is a [Union Find Data Structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

> It is a data structure that keeps track of a set of elements partitioned into a number of disjoint (nonoverlapping) subsets. It supports ... which subset a particular element is in.

As for implementation, we take all vertices as in different subset initially. For each edge, we check if the 2 ends are in the same set. If they are already in the same set, we detected a cycle; if not, we join them together.

Check [this article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find/) about how to use Union Find Data Structure to detect a cycle.

Time complexity of this approach is approximately `O(E)`, given that the [Inverse Ackermann function could be treated as a small constant (less than 5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse).

Comment: Note that the time complexity of the DFS in this case is just `O(V)`, since we stop as soon as we encounter a back edge, we have a guarantee we only traverse a tree and maybe one extra edge, and for a tree `Ө(E) = Ө(V)`, so `O(V + E) = O(V)`.